# Использование supervisord'a с помощью python

Tags: python, linux

Не могли бы вы на пальцах объяснить, что такое supervisord и с чем его едят. Желательно в примерах. В интрнете есть статьи, но они ориентированы на людей с опытом, а я не такой...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

supervisord это система "менеджмента" группы процессов. Зачем это нужно? Как часто у Вас возникает задача, что бы какой то процесс стартовал при старте системы, работал все время и если нечайно упадет, перезапускался? А ещё предоставлял web-интерфейс, что бы этим всем управлять. Это все можно  решить ручками. А можно довериться supervisord.

Он стартует при старте системы как классический демон и читая свой конфиг, запускает нужные процессы и следит за ними.

- Может собирать [логи](http://supervisord.org/logging.html) от приложений.
- Позволяет [красиво управлять](https://github.com/Gamegos/cesi) запущенными приложениями.
- Может и почту разослать, если что то [случилось](http://supervisord.org/events.html).
- А плагинами может следить за [Django](https://github.com/aleszoulek/django-dashvisor) к примеру.

То есть, вместо того, что бы это все писать ручками, можно взять готовое решение. Плюс ко всему, админу проще будет решить возникшую проблему. А если нужно что то сильно специфическое (например, через телеграм управлять сервером), то это можно плугином написать.

Документация http://supervisord.org/

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что ответственность у supervisord пересекается с systemd и подобными системными компонентами (для части задач одно вместо другого можно использовать)..